# WPF Facebook like scrollbar behavior using scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a simple scrollviewer setup in my wpf application. Everything works fine, Now I want my scrollviewer's content should use the space of my the scollbar as well, As my scrollbar is transparent it could easily display the content.

Just like the scrollbars in facebook. Attached is the image of the output. Green Section is the content and red section is scollviewer's area.

[image]

I am using WrapPanel in my scrollviewer, this is the code snippet

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1"                
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <WrapPanel x:Name="WrapPanel1" SizeChanged="WrapPanel1_SizeChanged" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the `ScrollViewer`'s `ControlTemplate` which should look like the one in this page : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the **ScrollViewer Control Template Example**, you can see that the `ScrollContentPresenter` is inside a `Border` which is inside the first row of a 2-rows `Grid`.

Setting the `RowSpan` to 2 for this `Border` would achieve the effect you want.